# How to re-setup swap partition in GPT system

Tags: 14.04, swap, gpt

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot on my windows 8 acer desktop pc. I am sure I set up a swap drive but now if I do `swapon -s` I don't seem to have a swap partition. Upon `sudo fdisk -l` I get:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x055144b6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I have corrected swap problems before on a non-GPT system and would appreciate some help in get my swap re-setup on GPT. 
My system shows the following:
`sudo gdisk /dev/sda` then `p` shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 531392B4-E90D-44D4-B066-9D0760AAE16B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1230847   600.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2         1230848         1845247   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1845248         2107391   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   4         2107392       161163263   75.8 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   5       161163264       317462527   74.5 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   6       317462528       348829695   15.0 GiB    2700  Basic data partition
   7       348829696       387891199   18.6 GiB    0700  
   8       387891200       583202815   93.1 GiB    8300  
   9       583202816       598827007   7.5 GiB     8200  
  10       598827008      1953523711   646.0 GiB   8300
```

My original swap was on no 9 above.

`blkid` shows:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="C8D83761D8374D46" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="ESP" UUID="B639-EA4B" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Acer" UUID="01D0215206ACFEE0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="DATA" UUID="01D0215209012810" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Push Button Reset" UUID="01D021528B28B4C0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="6D02-3AEA" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="775b2ce6-e738-40e5-828f-eccdf49cd63a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda10: UUID="22c6084f-1225-48eb-a295-5d1a0d3d8830" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Is there any swap listed in `/etc/fstab` ? If any, what is the line with swap ? Same question for `/etc/crypttab`

Comment: Used the fstab and cryptswap lines in your example below and it worked. Thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Crypted

To setup a **crypted swap**, add this line to `/etc/crypttab`

```
cryptswap   /dev/sda9    /dev/urandom     swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
```

then add this one in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap        none            swap    defaults        0       0
```

You may need to install *cryptsetup* package (`sudo apt-get install cryptsetup`).

and reboot

## Or not (crypted)

Run the command:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sda9
```

then, simply add a line in `/etc/fstab` like

```
/dev/sda9                     none            swap    defaults        0       0
```

and either reboot or run `sudo swapon -a`

## PARTUUID

In either case, it is better to use **PARTUUID** (because you use *GPT*) instead of the device name. Get the partition UUID with

```
sudo blkid -s PARTUUID /dev/sda9
```

and use it in `/etc/crypttab` or `/etc/fstab` with PARTUUID= instead of /dev/sda9

Comment: This has worked for me using crypted and uuid, although it was necessary to remove all traces of a swap in both fstab and cryptab and then reboot before starting with the above steps.